# Rust AWS SDK DynamoDB Conditional Check Error Handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Does the Rust AWS SDK provide information on where a DynamoDB conditional check failed exactly? I have multiple conditional checks and the Err response doesn't shed any light on which condition failed.

> TransactionCanceledException(TransactionCanceledException { message:
> Some("Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for
> specific reasons [None, ConditionalCheckFailed]"),
> cancellation_reasons: Some([CancellationReason { item: None, code:
> Some("None"), message: None }, CancellationReason { item: None, code:
> Some("ConditionalCheckFailed"), message: Some("The conditional request
> failed") }]), meta: ErrorMetadata { code:
> Some("TransactionCanceledException"), message: Some("Transaction
> cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons
> [None, ConditionalCheckFailed]"),

https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-dynamodb/latest/aws_sdk_dynamodb/types/error/struct.ConditionalCheckFailedException.html

```
let request = client
        .transact_write_items()
        .set_transact_items(Some(transact_items));

    match request.send().await {
        Err(err) => {
            match err.into_service_error() {
                aws_sdk_dynamodb::operation::transact_write_items::TransactWriteItemsError::TransactionCanceledException(i) => {
                    println!("reason: {:?}", &i.cancellation_reasons().unwrap());
                },
                _ => todo!(),
            };
```

> [CancellationReason { item: None, code: Some("None"), message: None },
> CancellationReason { item: None, code: Some("ConditionalCheckFailed"),
> message: Some("The conditional request failed") }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to supply the parameter `return_values_on_condition_check_failure` and set it to `ALL_OLD`:

https://docs.rs/rusoto_dynamodb/latest/rusoto_dynamodb/struct.Put.html

This will return the value of the item on the server side, which you can then understand why your condition failed.

`[None, ConditionalCheckFailed]` this already let's you know the condition failed for the second item in your transactional batch.

Comment: Adding the return_values_on_condition_check_failure didn't seem to help. ```[CancellationReason { item: None, code: Some("None"), message: None }, CancellationReason { item: None, code: Some("ConditionalCheckFailed"), message: Some("The conditional request failed") }]``` So it's pointing to the second check failing, but doesn't return any items

Comment: edited original post with more

Comment: Are you using DynamoDB Local?

Comment: No not using local

Comment: In not familiar with rust, maybe try call get item: https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-dynamodb/latest/src/aws_sdk_dynamodb/types/error/_conditional_check_failed_exception.rs.html#98

Comment: I found that when there's multiple transaction items in one request it doesn't return anything for item. But when there's only one transaction item in one request it does.

Comment: Interesting, I'll do some tests and bring it up with the team

Comment: Another thing, it looks like it returns the item that caused a PUT to fail but doesn't return anything when a condition check on a known item fails. Meaning, if I try to PUT an item that already exists, the transaction will fail and the item in the table is returned. But if I have a conditional check where I check if a certain attribute == a value on an item, it just fails, not returning anything. Which kinda makes sense

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So a conditional Put or Update will return the item, but a `ConditionCheck` will not?

Comment: As far as I can tell it only returns an item on a PUT. I'm guessing this is because when condition checking or updating we already know the item we are checking/updating in the table. A PUT is less clear. It returns the item that caused the PUT to fail, as this item might not be known to us before.